# Is this solution of PDE problem correct?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Solving a PDE problem, I obtain

```
DSolve[{D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {t, 2}], 
u[x, 0] == Piecewise[{{0, x < -1}, {x, x >= -1 && x < 0}, {1 - x, x >= 0 && x <= 1}, {0, x > 1}}], 
Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == Piecewise[{{0, x < -1}, {1, x >= -1 && x <= 1}, {0, 
  x > 1}}]}, u, {x, t}]


(*{{u -> Function[{x, t}, 
     (1/2)*Integrate[
           Piecewise[
             {{0, K[1] < -1}, 
               {1, K[1] >= -1 && 
                 K[1] <= 1}}], 
           {K[1], x - t, 
             t + x}] + (1/2)*
         (Piecewise[
              {{0, x - t < -1}, 
                {x - t, x - t >= 
                   -1 && x - t < 0}, 
                {t - x + 1, 
                 x - t >= 0 && 
                  x - t <= 1}}] + 
            Piecewise[
              {{0, t + x < -1}, 
                {t + x, t + x >= 
                   -1 && t + x < 0}, 
                {-t - x + 1, 
                 t + x >= 0 && 
                  t + x <= 1}}])]}}*)
```

That's all nice until I plot it by

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. %[[1]]], {x, -2, 2}, {t, 0, 2},PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Saying nothing about the quality of the above plot, I have doubts whether the initial condition

```
Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == Piecewise[{{0, x < -1}, {1, x >= -1 && x <= 1}, {0, x > 1}}]
```

is met even in the sense of a weak solution.

Thoughts of Mathematica users on that topic are welcome.

Comment: Just to compare, Maple 2020 produces $$u \left( x,t \right) =1/2\,
\cases{0&$-t+x<-1$\cr -t+x&$-t+x<0$\cr 1+t-x&$-t+x\leq 1$\cr 0&$1<-t+x$\cr}
-1/2\,\cases{0&$-t+x\leq -1$\cr -t+x+1&$-t+x<1$\cr 2&$1\leq -t+x$\cr}+
1/2\,
\cases{0&$t+x<-1$\cr t+x&$t+x<0$\cr 1-t-x&$t+x\leq 1$\cr 0&$1<t+x$\cr}
+1/2\,\cases{0&$t+x\leq -1$\cr 1+t+x&$t+x<1$\cr 2&$1\leq t+x$\cr}
 $$ and an unclear plot.

Comment: Try `Which` instead of `Piecewise`! Now you can check the initial conditions without message `Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {-(10499571/3500000)-t,-(10499571/3500000)+t} are real. Adding assumptions may help.`!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Thank you for your interest to the question and constructive suggestion. It is not so simple to realize it. I work with the result `DSolve` as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified it on my own through

```
s={{u -> Function[{x, t}, 
 (1/2)*Integrate[
       Piecewise[
         {{0, K[1] < -1}, 
           {1, K[1] >= -1 && 
             K[1] <= 1}}], 
       {K[1], x - t, 
         t + x}] + (1/2)*
     (Piecewise[
          {{0, x - t < -1}, 
            {x - t, x - t >= 
               -1 && x - t < 0}, 
            {t - x + 1, 
             x - t >= 0 && 
              x - t <= 1}}] + 
        Piecewise[
          {{0, t + x < -1}, 
            {t + x, t + x >= 
               -1 && t + x < 0}, 
            {-t - x + 1, 
             t + x >= 0 && 
              t + x <= 1}}])]}};
Plot[D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. s[[1]]], t] /. t -> 0, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]
 The question is closed.